# Sizzle as a function in object

Tags: javascript, object, object-literal, sizzle

I have JavaScript code with object like:

```
var myObj = {
    SomeVal: 1,
    Sizzle: function(){
        //sizzle
    }
};
```

How can I include Sizzle selector engine as an function in object?
In Sizzle source code I found a function Sizzle, but source code also have a lot of code outside of function.

After include I can call:

```
myObj.Sizzle('#elem');
```

Comment: Why don't make the Sizzle function to return `Sizzle('#elem')` result ... something like this: 
`Sizzle: function(selector){
  return Sizzle(selector);
}`

Comment: I just don't want to load Sizzle globally to user browser. I need to load and  use Sizzle inside anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

as @leo.fcx mentioned, return the Sizzle engine in your method. Maybe this will help:

```
var myObj = {
  SomeVal: 1,
  Sizzle: function(){
    return Sizzle.apply(window, arguments);
  }
};
```